# Discord.py: assigning a role to a different person using a slash command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a score keeper bot that runs on slash commands. Within the "add points" command - which only I can use - I want the bot to automatically grant the person receiving the points a new role at certain points thresholds.

Everything works up until here.

```
        guild = bot.get_guild(int([a guild ID number is here]))
        player = guild.fetch_member(int(user_id))  #the user_id variable is the ID number for the Discord user who is receiving the points.
        if(bumped==True):
            rank_one = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Test Rank")
            await player.add_roles(rank_one)
```

At which point it complains that:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

I have been going in circles all day trying different things, but everything I can find online is assuming that the person being given the role is the one commanding the bot, or is reacting to it, or something along those lines. But I have to be the one commanding the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `await guild.fetch_member()`